# How to replace a CLOB column by a varchar2(4000) column?

Tags: oracle

The following code seems to do the job, but I doubt, that it is robust enough.

```
SET serveroutput on 

DECLARE
    v_isclob PLS_INTEGER;
    v_cmd    VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE when exists (select * from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_to_modify' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND DATA_TYPE = 'CLOB') then 1 else 0 end into v_isclob FROM DUAL;
    IF v_isclob > 0 THEN
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MyTable RENAME COLUMN Column_to_modify  TO XXX';

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD Column_to_modify varchar2(4000)';

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE MyTable SET Column_to_modify = SUBSTR(XXX, 1, 4000)';

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN XXX';
            dbms_output.put_line ('++    Column_to_modify modified to varchar2(4000)');
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THen
            dbms_output.put_line ('##### Error while modifying Column_to_modify');
        END;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line ('     Column_to_modify is varchar(4000)');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

How can I improve the code?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest adding a temp column rather than renaming the existing one. In Oracle 10g I created a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE  "TEST" 
   (    "A" CLOB
   )
```

I then inserted data so that the results of length calls are as follows:

```
select length(a) from test
```

**Result:**

```
"LENGTH(A)"
12308
12308
12308
12308
12308
```

I then altered the table as follows:

```
alter table "TEST" modify
("A" VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL)
/
```

As expected receive the following error:
**ORA-22859: invalid modification of columns**

Change the column using the following script:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD temp VARCHAR2(4000);
UPDATE TEST
   SET temp = DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (a, 4000),
       a = NULL;

ALTER TABLE TEST DROP COLUMN A;
ALTER TABLE TEST RENAME COLUMN temp TO A;
```

Reissue the length sql:

```
"LENGTH(A)"
4000
4000
4000
4000
4000
```

Comment: nice. Maybe a trim around the substr is useful? and, why use a = NULL if you drop it later?

Comment: @Wouter Maybe setting the old column to null is intended to reduce memory consumption during the transition?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't handle to presence of an existing column named XXX.  You might consider at least making the name a bit more obscure.  Perhaps a quoted string of 30 mixed case letters and numbers.  Even better you could handle the name exception and try a different name.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle recommend using their specific DBMS package for this:

- [Performing Online Redefinition with DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#ADMIN11668)

If using the more traditional method when would suggest the following to preserve the order of columns.

```
 ALTER TABLE TEST ADD temp VARCHAR2(4000);
 UPDATE TEST SET temp = DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (a, 4000), a = NULL;
 COMMIT;
 ALTER TABLE TEST MODIFY A VARCHAR2(4000);
 UPDATE TEST SET A = temp;
 COMMIT;
 ALTER TABLE TEST DROP COLUMN temp;
```